# How to change the last number after reaching maxLength

Tags: java, android, xml

On EditText i'm using android:maxLength="3" with numbers only as input in .xml 
But when the limit is reached and the user continues to click the number stays the same.

I want to change the last digit when the user continues to click.

SAMPLE:
User clicks 3 numbers = 456
on the 4-th time he clicks '0' = 450
(The first 2 numbers stay the same except the last one which will change with every click until he confirms the number)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through the documentation and search in StackOverflow for similar questions before asking them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer by myself and here is the solution that works for me.

In the onClick() method just before I use .append (to show the number on the screen) I inserted small helper method checkLength() to check and restrict more than 3 numbers.

in .java file:

```
private void checkLength() {
    Editable editable = mNumber.getText();
    int charCount = editable.length();
    if (charCount > 2) {
        editable.delete(charCount - 1, charCount);
    }
```

in .xml file:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:maxLength="3"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:maxLength="n"` limits the `EditText` from getting the key pressed by the user after the maximum length is reached.

So if you want to add last pressed number at the end and remove the first digit of the present number in the `EditText` set the `android:maxLength` value to a number greater than n. (n=3 in your case).

Then use [setOnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnKeyListener(android.view.View.OnKeyListener)) to do as you wish with the number in the `EditText`.

In `setOnKeyListener` use `getText()` to get the number in the string and alter as you wish and then use `setText()` to make the changes reflect in the `EditText`